# How to open dropdown button by clicking on text?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I'm setting a dropdown button on my website, but I get this weird thing. The dropdown part only shows when I click on the box of the button, but not when I click on "Tools". What am I doing wrong? Thanks so much!

(Ok, W3 school will not take the code to save, so I have to do this manually)

```js
    /* When the user clicks on the button, 
    toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    }
    
    // Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
          var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
          if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
            openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

```css
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      min-width: 160px;
      overflow: auto;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }
    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }
    button.dropbtn{
      background:none;
      border:none;
      padding:0;
    }
    .dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
    .show {display: block;}
```

```html
    <body>
    <div class="column-outlet">
      <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn"><strong>Tools</strong></button>
      <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <li class="force-css"><a href="#">Blok 1</a></li>
        <li class="force-css"><a href="#">Blok 1</a></li>
        <li class="force-css"><a href="#">Blok 1</a></li>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: show us your code

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Guys, calm down :P, he is **editing** above because the **provided link to try his code didn't work**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the strong tag from the button.

```
<body>
<div class="column-outlet">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Tools</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <li class="force-css"><a href="#">Blok 1</a></li>
    <li class="force-css"><a href="#">Blok 1</a></li>
    <li class="force-css"><a href="#">Blok 1</a></li>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Omg lol that was the only thing causing this? :D Thanks man! If my rep was high enough, I'd upvote this!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use  tag into button but text-weight in CSS and use UL tag to create the list

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
    toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    }
    
    // Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
          var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
          if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
            openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

```css
.dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
     
    }
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      min-width: 160px;
      overflow: auto;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }
    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }
    button.dropbtn{
     font-weight: 700;
      background:none;
      border:none;
      padding:0;
    }
    .dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
    .show {display: block;}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="column-outlet">
      <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Tools</button>
      <ul id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <li class="force-css"><a href="#">Blok 1</a></li>
        <li class="force-css"><a href="#">Blok 1</a></li>
        <li class="force-css"><a href="#">Blok 1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: That's indeed the way I should've done it, although I always use "font-weight:bold;". Thanks! :)