# Dropdown menu JS

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, menu, hover, dropdown

Based on this post - [How to open dropdown button by clicking on text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55628624/how-to-open-dropdown-button-by-clicking-on-text/63899517#63899517)

I'm trying to add this dropdown effect when you hover the link "tools" in addition to this script but with any success (I would like to keep onclick at the same time). Someone could help me on this ? I'm sure it's quite easy but I'm very not an expert in JS sorry. Spent some hours without finding any solution :(

Many thanks for the help.

JS:

```
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to add this -

```
 document.getElementByClassName(".dropbtn").onmouseenter = function(){
 document.getElementByClassName("dropdown-content").classList.contains("show");
```

}

CSS

```
  .dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
 
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
button.dropbtn{
 font-weight: 700;
  background:none;
  border:none;
  padding:0;
}
.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
.show {display: block;}
```

HTML

```
<div>
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Tools</button>
  <ul id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a href="#">Blok 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blok 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blok 1</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you tried writing it yourself? if it is so, show us your code which will help us in providing solution.

Comment: Hi Ambrish, thank you! :)  I edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

Hover event can be handled with `mouseenter` event

I have also included `mouseleave` event which can be used to do something on mouse leave event.

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
    toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    }
    
    // Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
          var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
          if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
            openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
          }
        }
      }
    }

$(".dropbtn").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    },
    //mouseleave: function () {
        //do something on mouse pointer leave event
    //}
});
```

```css
.dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
     
    }
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      min-width: 160px;
      overflow: auto;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }
    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }
    button.dropbtn{
     font-weight: 700;
      background:none;
      border:none;
      padding:0;
    }
    .dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
    .show {display: block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="column-outlet">
      <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Tools</button>
      <ul id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <li class="force-css"><a href="#">Blok 1</a></li>
        <li class="force-css"><a href="#">Blok 1</a></li>
        <li class="force-css"><a href="#">Blok 1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

PS: This is a modified answer. Credits to Uncoke for original answer at [How to open dropdown button by clicking on text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55628624/how-to-open-dropdown-button-by-clicking-on-text/63899517#63899517)

Comment: Thank you very much Ambrish! But unfortunately this script (mouseenter event) doesn't work on Cargo Collective. Something wrong with the load of the jquery file I guess. I'm still trying to find the solution...

Comment: @bigbox  What is "Cargo Collective" ?